# Why can't opos find my cash drawer using common controls?

Tags: c#, opos

In much the same way as [this guy was having a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101966/error-fails-to-open-device-when-using-esc-opos-from-vb6), I'm having a similar problem...

My cashdrawer connects to the pc via an RJ11 (I think its 11 anyway...) connection to my printer which is a `Partner RP-600 Thermal Printer`.

I've got the printer working well, but I can't get the cash drawer to open.

[image: opos cash drawer config]

Basically my thinking on how this should work (based on my limited understanding is this:

1. Open printer
2. Claim printer
3. Enable printer
4. Open cash drawer
5. Claim cash drawer
6. Enable cash drawer
7. Open hardware drawer

I've tried this a number of ways and I get the following errors:

> OPOS_E_CLOSED = 101, but most commonly
>   OPOS_E_NOEXIST = 109

If I set it to `drawer.Open("rp-600 printer")`, I get `OPOS_E_ILLEGAL = 106`

My code follows:

```
    using OPOSCONSTANTSLib;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using OposPOSPrinter_CCO;
    using OposCashDrawer_CCO;

    namespace PosPrinterTest
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
        private OPOSPOSPrinterClass printer = null;
        private OPOSCashDrawerClass drawer = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            printer = new OPOSPOSPrinterClass();
            drawer = new OPOSCashDrawerClass();

            _IOPOSPOSPrinterEvents_StatusUpdateEventEventHandler SUEH =
                new _IOPOSPOSPrinterEvents_StatusUpdateEventEventHandler(
                    PrinterStatusUpdateHandler);
            printer.StatusUpdateEvent += SUEH;

            _IOPOSCashDrawerEvents_StatusUpdateEventEventHandler DSUEH = new _IOPOSCashDrawerEvents_StatusUpdateEventEventHandler(CashDrawerStatusUpdateHandler);
            drawer.StatusUpdateEvent += DSUEH;
        }

        private void AddList(object listline)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(listline);
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
        }

        private void OpenCashDrawer()
        {
            AddList("+Open drawer");

            int Result = drawer.Open("rpd");
            AddList(String.Format("  1-Open drawer: RC = {0}", Result));
            Result = drawer.ClaimDevice(1000);
            AddList(String.Format("  2-Claim drawer: RC = {0}", Result));
            drawer.DeviceEnabled = true;
            Result = drawer.ResultCode;
            AddList(String.Format("  3-Enable drawer: RC = {0}", Result));
            Result = drawer.OpenDrawer();
            AddList(String.Format("  4-Open drawer: RC = {0}", Result));

            AddList(String.Format("-Open drawer: {0}", ((Result == (int)OPOS_Constants.OPOS_SUCCESS) ? "Succeeded" : "Failed")));
            AddList(String.Empty);
        }

        private void CloseCashDrawer()
        {
            AddList("+Close drawer");

            int Result = drawer.ReleaseDevice();
            AddList(String.Format("  Release drawer: RC = {0}", Result));
            AddList("-Release drawer: " + ((Result == (int)OPOS_Constants.OPOS_SUCCESS) ? "Succeeded" : "Failed"));

            Result = drawer.Close();
            AddList(String.Format("  Close drawer: RC = {0}", Result));
            AddList("-Close drawer: " + ((Result == (int)OPOS_Constants.OPOS_SUCCESS) ? "Succeeded" : "Failed"));
            AddList(String.Empty);
        }

        private void Print()
        {
            AddList("+Print");

            int Result = printer.PrintNormal(2, "\x1B|cA\x1B|2COPOS POSPrinter\x1B|1C\nvia Microsoft.NET\n\n");

            AddList(String.Format("  Print: BC = {0}", Result));
            AddList(String.Format("-Print: {0}", ((Result == (int)OPOS_Constants.OPOS_SUCCESS) ? "Succeeded" : "Failed")));

            Result = printer.CutPaper(100);
            AddList(String.Format("  Cut: BC = {0}", Result));
            AddList(String.Format("-Cut: {0}", ((Result == (int)OPOS_Constants.OPOS_SUCCESS) ? "Succeeded" : "Failed")));
            AddList(String.Empty);
        }

        private void OpenPrinter()
        {
            AddList("+Open printer");

            int Result = printer.Open("rp-600 printer");
            AddList(String.Format("  Open: RC = {0}", Result));

            if (Result == (int)OPOS_Constants.OPOS_SUCCESS)
            {
                Result = printer.ClaimDevice(1000);
                AddList(String.Format("  Claim printer: RC = {0}", Result));

                if (Result == (int)OPOS_Constants.OPOS_SUCCESS)
                {
                    printer.DeviceEnabled = true;
                    Result = printer.ResultCode;
                    AddList(String.Format("  Enable printer: RC = {0}>", Result));
                }
            }
            AddList(String.Format("-Open: {0}", ((Result == (int)OPOS_Constants.OPOS_SUCCESS) ? "Succeeded" : "Failed")));
            AddList(String.Empty);
        }

        private void ClosePrinter()
        {
            AddList("+Close printer");

            int Result = printer.ReleaseDevice();
            AddList(String.Format("  Release printer: RC = {0}", Result));
            AddList("-Release printer: " + ((Result == (int)OPOS_Constants.OPOS_SUCCESS) ? "Succeeded" : "Failed"));

            Result = printer.Close();
            AddList(String.Format("  Close printer: RC = {0}", Result));
            AddList("-Close printer: " + ((Result == (int)OPOS_Constants.OPOS_SUCCESS) ? "Succeeded" : "Failed"));
            AddList(String.Empty);
        }

        private void PrinterStatusUpdateHandler(int nStatus)
        {
            AddList("  P StatusUpdate: " + nStatus);
        }

        private void CashDrawerStatusUpdateHandler(int nStatus)
        {
            AddList(String.Format("  CD Status Update: {0}", nStatus));
        }

        private void btnTender_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //OpenPrinter();
            //Print();
            //ClosePrinter();

            OpenCashDrawer();
            CloseCashDrawer();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the device name I'm specifying in OpenCashDrawer() is the same as the device name I set in opos.

So what am I doing wrong that's preventing opos from finding the cash drawer?

Comment: The drawer and printer are separate devices, you shouldn't need to open/claim the printer in order to use the drawer. Also, if you haven't already, try installing the common control objects (located here: http://monroecs.com/oposccos_current.htm).

Comment: @JoshAnderson just to be clear, you are aware that the cash drawer doesn't connect to the pc, but instead to the printer, right? Because I'm still getting the 109 error code

Comment: I'm aware, those cash drawers can be pesky.
Just seeing your latest edit, I thought you were using Microsoft's POS for .Net instead of directly using the common control classes. I'm less familiar with them, but is there a method to enumerate through every installed device of a particular type just to see if it shows up? It could also be that the _drawer.Open() method expects a service object name, rather than the logical device name.

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a method in the OPOSCashDrawerClass for that

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows that the cashdrawer LDN is "rp-cashdrawer", but your code is using "rpd".

```
drawer.Open("rpd");
```

You should be opening the device with a configured LDN, like:

```
drawer.Open("rp-cashdrawer");
```

Comment: While this is a valid point, the reason the cash drawer couldn't open was because I needed a specific driver for the cash drawer. Once I got that, the code worked (after I targeted the correct device in the .Open() method.